# Сложное ли предложение?

Tags: члены-предложения

Является ли это предложение сложным?

> ...где мне было суждено уцелеть, а другим — погибнуть

С одной стороны, похоже на простое, особенно если его немного переделать: **было суждено уцелеть** мне и **погибнуть** другим. И то, и другое было суждено, видимо, кем-то одним.

Или это сложное предложение? 
"где мне **было суждено уцелеть**, а другим *(было суждено) погибнуть*". Выделенные части — две грамматические основы двух разных безличных предложений, относящихся к одному союзу?

P.S. Главная сложность для меня — это то, что я не могу понять, являются ли "было суждено уцелеть" и "погибуть" частью одного сказуемого? Если нет, то являются ли они однородными сказуемыми?

Comment: Выбрал ответ Vera, ибо он более полный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложения с однородными сказуемыми в некоторых случаях могут рассматриваться как сложные предложения, при этом на решение оказывают влияние различные факторы. Чем больше спаянность сказуемых (компактно расположенных, имеющих одинаковую морфологию и т.д.), тем ближе они к однородным сказуемым.

В частности однородными считаются сказуемые, если связываются их именные части или инфинитивы: осень была холодная, дождливая. Он любит купаться и загорать.

(1) Где мне было суждено уцелеть, а другим — погибнуть. Этот вариант ближе к однородным придаточным (во втором пропущено сказуемое, неполное предложение).

(2)  Где было суждено уцелеть мне и погибнуть другим. Этот вариант ближе к однородным сказуемым.

Comment: Vera, если во втором предложении пропущено сказуемое, то что тогда такое "погибнуть"? Дополнение?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Ему суждено (что?) погибнуть.  Ему суждено (что?) большое будущее.  Тогда инфинитив - это дополнение, то есть объектный инфинитив. В этом случае источник действия стихийный и не совпадает с собственными действиями субъекта, выраженного в безличных предложениях формой Д.п. Сравнить: Здесь можно погибнуть  - инфинитив входит в сказуемое.

Answer (score 1):

> ...мне **было суждено** уцелеть, а другим — погибнуть

Предложение простое, безличное, осложнённое однородными дополнениями ***уцелеть, погибнуть.***

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю что оно сложное. В нём 2 подлежащих, 2 сказуемых. Ну про подлежащее я не уверена,но сказуемых точно 2. Значит оно сложное.

Comment: Подробнее надо. И аргументированнее.

Answer (score 0):

Сказуемых может даже 3. Суждено 3-е(я так думаю)

Comment: подробнее пишите, пожалуйста. надо не думать, а обосновывать.